# Browser Console error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/lib/ReactPerf' from 'react/lib/ReactAddonsDOMDependencies.js'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

This started today after saving the `react-addons-css-transition-group` npm package as a dependency.

I then went down a rabbit hole of updating, adding & removing various dependencies as well as making sure all the react-related dependencies share the same versioning. I think I'm back to where I was before adding the `react-addons-css-transition-group` dependency, aside from updates, but I'm still getting this error and I can't find anything online relating to it specifically.

package.json if that helps:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern public",
    "start": "brunch watch --server",
    "knex": "knex",
    "heroku-postbuild": "brunch build --production; knex migrate:latest",
    "nf": "nf start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "auto-reload-brunch": "^2.7.1",
    "axios": "^0.14.0",
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "bcrypt": "^0.8.7",
    "bcrypt-as-promised": "^1.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "boom": "^4.0.0",
    "brunch": "^2.9.1",
    "clean-css-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-validation": "^1.0.1",
    "humps": "^1.1.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "joi": "^9.0.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "knex": "^0.12.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.3",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "multer": "1.1.0",
    "pg": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.8",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^2.8.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.7.0",
    "weak-key": "^1.0.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.2.2",
    "eslint-config-ryansobol": "^8.0.0",
    "foreman": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "7.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting the node-modules folder and re-importing all dependencies.

My dependencies and devDependencies sections look like that after the re-import:

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.16.5",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-perf": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "auto-reload-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.11.1",
    "brunch": "^2.4.0",
    "clean-css-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "css-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "^2.0.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a [Brunch bug](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1591).
We added a workaround in React 15.4.2 but can’t guarantee it won’t break again.